# How to fit a casement window stay restrictor

Tags: windows

I picked up some casement window stay restrictors from a window place, but they didn't come with instructions. The device looks like [this one](https://www.interlockna.com/en/site/interlock/products/casement-awning-window-solutions/restrictors1/).

Basically there's a track that I'll screw to the inner part of the window frame, and attached to that is an arm with another plate that'll go to the window.

What I'm wondering is how I should measure where on the window I should attach the plate. Because if I get this wrong, then I won't be able to close the window (as the part that travels in the track will hit the stop before the window is fully closed. Or if I'm too conservative I'm wasting window opening power.

Googling gives conflicting advice, over whether the track should just go next to the hinge track that's already in place, or to the opposite end of the window. Even found some conflicting idea on whether the track part goes onto the window frame or the window.

Comment: Why don't you contact the "window place" or the manufacturer to ask them for instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you purchased or what you are using these parts for or how you are using these parts Attaching these to an existing casement window is an "exact science" and must be done exactly or you will have trouble with the window operation. If you are replacing the hardware on an existing casement I would recommend that you consult the window mfg for help.